# kube2sky in kubernetes with multiple api servers

Tags: kubernetes

It a Kubernetes cluster where everything is highly available, the DNS is a key piece of the system, everything relies on the DNS.

The pod kube2sky has a parameter "-kube_master_url" where, afaik, you can only specify one api server node.

You might have multiple api servers for redundancy behing a service, but if the one that kube2sky is using gets down, the whole DNS system gets down too, hence, the highly availabily of the cluster is gone.

For other pods, you can use the internal DNS name of the api server service, but in this case, you can't since this is the actual DNS service.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

In its standard configuration, kube2sky doesn't actually rely on having a single apiserver IP address to use. Instead, it uses the virtual IP of the `kubernetes` service that gets auto-created in every cluster, and which the kube-proxy sets up iptables rules for. It's [briefly explained in the docs on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns#how-does-it-work).

Also, [it's recommended that replicated masters are put behind a load balancer](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/high-availability/#load-balancing) in such high-availability configurations to avoid problems like this with client tools.

Comment: But that kubernetes service uses port 443, so kube2sky would need the certificates to connect. Is there any way to set them? Or, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Use the `--kubecfg-file` option described here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns/kube2sky. That will allow you to specify CA and certificates and endpoint of the master. You can use the same configuration file used by  the host running the kubelet by mounting the directory containing the configuration file into the pod.